# No provider for Array

Tags: angular

I just started with Angular RC6. I imported HttpModule inside my @NgModule decorator.

However I get this exception: No provider for Array!

How can I fix this?

-- edit--:
For some reason this error is caused by:

```
constructor(private myService: CustomService, public items: Item[]) { }
```

Comment: Please add the code that allows to reproduce the issue. According to the error message you try to inject an array somewhere and don't have a matching provider registered. I guess it's in the 7th file line 13 ;-)

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in app/home/home.html:9:4 caused by: No provider for Array!

Comment: That's exactly where the error is. Should I make it an answer so you can accept it? ;-p I think I was quite close with `line 13`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it is caused by: constructor(private myService: CustomService, public items: Item[]) { }

Comment: That's better :) See my answer. I don't know what the expected behavior is. Do you expect Angular to ignore that parameter? Do you expect it to pass something to the constructor for this parameter? If yes, then what should that be?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If a constructor of a service, component, or directive contains parameters, Angulars dependency injection tries to find a provider to get a value from it that it then passes to the constructor.

You don't have a provider registered for the type `Item[]`.
Either

- you register a provider
- you add `@Optional()` before `public items: Item[]` so Angulars DI is allowed to ignore the parameter if it doesn't find a provider
- you remove the parameter from the constructor.

Comment: Why do I need a provider for Item? It's just a simple model class. Class is imported at the top. But it is still complaining about the array... Even when i removed the parameter from the constructor. This fails: public items: Item[] = [];

Comment: As mentioned, when Angulars DI creates an instance it tries to find values (from providers) in can pass to the constructor parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Just initialize the array outside the constructor and create it in the constructor i.e.

```
export class Animal{    

    public animals: Animal[]; //initializing outside the constructor

    constructor(private animal: Animal) {

        this.animals = new Array<Animal>(); //creating inside the constructor

        animals.push(animal); //adding element to the array
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `bindings` or `providers` in your code

for example

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'test-app',
    bindings: [ServiceName]
})
```